# why we don't have : $\lim_{z \to 1} f(z) = \sum_{n= 0}^\infty a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let's consider a power series : $\sum a_nz^n$ with radius of convergence $R \geq 1$.

Moreover let's denote :

$$C = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \mid z \mid \leq 1 \}$$
Now let's define :

$$f(z) = \sum a_nz^n, \forall z \in C$$

Now, we know that $f$ is $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$, so it's continuous on $C$.

So in this case why don't we have :

$$\lim_{z \to 1, z \in C} f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n $$

Normally by the continuity of $f$ this is always true ?

Comment: It would be true for $R\gt 1$, so you might think about the case $R=1$ in more detail.

Comment: Knowing that the radius of convergence is $1$ says nothing about convergence of the power series for $|z|=1$... Thus $f$ is not necessarily defined on $C$.

Comment: What would it be true? A power series may not converge on the frontier of its disk of convergence.

Comment: Note that even if the series converges at $1$ when $R=1$, this limit may not exist since you could attempt to plug in values of $z$ outside of the radius of convergence. In some sense, you would have to take the limit from within ($z_n$ is in the unit ball). My point being that you have to be extra careful about what limits mean with power series.

Comment: @CameronWilliams nope look more carefully at my limit.

Comment: @CameronWilliams On the limit it’s actually $z \in C$.

Comment: Oh I missed it! Didn't realize you had the limit different in the title and the post. Carry on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that saying the radius of convergence is $ R =1$ means the power serie converges for all $\mid z \mid < 1$.

So here using the continuity doesn’t mean anything because we can’t say anything for $z =1$.

Your equality is true if : $R > 1$.
You can also use Abel theorem to proove that your equality is true when you have some extra conditions.

Comment: I fixed a minor typo for you. Hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 1):

A power series may not converge on the border of its disk f convergence.

**Simple example**

The power series $$f_1(z) = \frac{1}{1-z} = \sum\limits_{n \ge 0} z^n$$ is convergent on the unit disk $\mathbb U$ and therefore continuous at every point of that disk. However the power series diverges at $z=1$.

**More funny example**

I give an example of a [A POWER SERIES CONVERGING EVERYWHERE ON ITS CIRCLE OF CONVERGENCE DEFINING A NON-CONTINUOUS FUNCTION](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/power-series-converging-everywhere-on-its-circle-of-convergence-defining-a-non-continuous-function/) in my [math counterexamples blog](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/).

Comment: Answers and questions should be self-contained...